# mongoengine access gridfs in multiple databases

Tags: mongoengine, gridfs

I've been accessing my other database just fine using `db_alias` for most fields. However, for models with `FileField()` or `ImageField()` I have not been able to access the file in the other database. Does `db_alias` not properly link to fs.files and fs.chunks in the other database?

```
class File(db.Document):
     file = db.ImageField()
     meta = {"db_alias": "OtherDB"}

for i in File.objects.all():
     print i.file          # Shows '<ImageGridFsProxy: (no file)>'
     print i.file.length   # Shows 'AttributeError'
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching through mongoengine issues reports on github I came across one that gave me a hint. Basically, for `FileField()` or `ImageField()` it is necessary to place db_alias directly into the field. For example, this works:

```
class File(db.Document):
     file = db.ImageField(db_alias="OtherDB")
```